# Schedule at a specific time with delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Is there a way to schedule a job at a specific time with delayed_job through the "delay" method, not through handle_asynchronously? Something like:

```
  class.delay.method(param), :run_at => Proc.new {time}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figured it out. You can run delayed_job by passing run_at as a param to delay.

```
  class.delay(run_at: 5.hours.from_now).method(param)
```

Comment: @AceDimashuhid you can also use `handle_asynchronously` which expect a proc where you can specify `run_at` options as well but, even your answer is correct too

Comment: @Viren Yes you are correct. I was trying to avoid the handle asynchronously because it seems much simpler this way, that's why i was looking for this answer. thanks